# Splitting contents in textfile

Tags: python

I have a text file that contains the following:

```
Number1 (E, P) (F, H)
Number2 (A, B) (C, D)
Number3 (I, J) (O, Z)
```

I know more or less how to read it and how to get the values of it into my program, but I wanted to know how to correctly split into "Number 1", "(E,P)" and "(F, H)". Also later, I want to be able to check in my program if "Number1" contains "(E, P)" or not.

```
def read_srg(name):
    filename = name + '.txt'
    fp = open(filename)
    lines = fp.readlines()

    R = {}
    for line in lines:
        ??? = line.split()

    fp.close()

    return R
```

Comment: Are there always exactly two parenthesized pairs?

Comment: Yes, the format of the file is always the same

Comment: If there is space between E, and P then you cannot use `line.split()` like that. I guess when you split what you are expecting is getting only three values'`[ "Number1", "(E, P)", "(F, H)" ]` but from what you are doing you will get `[ "Number1", "(E," , "P)", "(F," , "H)" ]`. For accurate results you might have to use regex.

Answer (score 6):

I think the easiest/most reliable way would be to use a regex:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r"([^()]*) (\([^()]*\)) (\([^()]*\))")
with open("myfile.txt") as text:
   for line in text:
       contents = regex.match(line)
       if contents:
           label, g1, g2 = contents.groups()
           # now do something with these values, e. g. add them to a list
```

**Explanation:**

```
([^()]*)      # Match any number of characters besides parentheses --> group 1
[ ]           # Match a space
(\([^()]*\))  # Match (, then any non-parenthesis characters, then ) --> group 2
[ ]           # Match a space
(\([^()]*\))  # Match (, then any non-parenthesis characters, then ) --> group 3
```

Comment: Well, it avoids having to define a logic not to split the string while between parentheses...

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I don't know where the general resentment against regex stems from. It is not always the easiest too, but for stuff like this it is the correct tool, so you better have it in your toolbox

Comment: I do not resent it, I respect it but I avoid it whenever I can. This is almost [Brainf**k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) syntax..

Comment: what is regex.match(s) ? it says that s is not defined and I do not know what it is exactly

Comment: Oops, I neglected to update a variable name - that should be `line`, not `s`.

Comment: Formatting error causes the code below `for` to be outside the loop.

Comment: @TimPietzcker yeah this is perfect! the only problem is that I think label, g1 and g2 only keep the value of the last line in the text file. How to keep all of them?

Comment: You could define a list like `results = []` before the loop and do `results.append((label, g1, g2))` in the loop if you can't do the processing within the loop itself.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the whitespaces within the parentheses, you better go with a [*regular expression*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), than just splitting lines.

Here's your `read_srg` function, with the regex check integrated:

```
import re

def read_srg(name):
    with open('%s.txt' % (name, ), 'r') as text:
        matchstring = r'(Number[0-9]+) (\([A-Z,\s]+\)) (\([A-Z,\s]+\))'
        R = {}
        for i, line in enumerate(text):
            match = re.match(matchstring, line)
            if not match:
                print 'skipping exception found in line %d: %s' % (i + 1, line)
                continue
            key, v1, v2 = match.groups()
            R[key] = v1, v2
        return R

from pprint import pformat
print pformat(read_srg('example'))
```

To read your dictionary and perform checks on keys and values, you can later do something like:

```
test_dict = read_srg('example')
for key, (v1, v2) in test_dict.iteritems():
    matchstring = ''
    if 'Number1' in key and '(E, P)' in v1:
        matchstring = 'match found: '
    print '%s%s > %s %s' % (matchstring, key, v1, v2)
```

---

A big advantage of this approach is that you can also use your regex to check that your file isn't malformed for some reason.
This is why the matching rule is quite strict:

`matchstring = r'(Number[0-9]+) (\([A-Z,\s]+\)) (\([A-Z,\s]+\))'`

- `(Number[0-9]+)` will match only words made of `Number` followed by any number of digits
- `(\([A-Z,\s]+\))` will match only strings enclosed into `()` which contain capital letters or `,` or a whitespace

I read in your comment that the format of the file is always the same, so I'm assuming it is procedurally generated.
Still, you might want to check its integrity (or to be sure that your code does not break if at some point the procedure generating the txt file changes its formatting).
Depending how strict you want your sanity check to be, you can push the above even further:

- if you know there should never be more than 3 digits after `Number`, you might change `(Number[0-9]+)` to `(Number[0-9]{1,3})` (which limits the match to 1, 2 or 3 digits)
- if you want to be sure the format in parentheses is always two single capital letters split by `", "` you can change `(\([A-Z,\s]+\))` to `(\([A-Z], [A-Z]\))`

Comment: I was half way through writing the answer, when I saw @TimPietzcker had already replied with a similar suggestion :/
I'm glad to hear that something in this explanation was anyway handy :)

Answer (score 0):

You were really close. Try this:

```
def read_srg(name):    
    with open(name + '.txt', 'r') as f:
        R = {}
        for line in f:
            line = line.replace(', ', ',')  # Number1 (E, P) (F, H) -> Number1 (E,P) (F,H)
            header, *contents = line.strip().split()  # `header` gets the first item of the list and all the rest go to `contents`
            R[header] = contents
    return R
```

---

Checking for membership can be later done like so:

```
if "(E,P)" in R["Number1"]:
    # do stuff
```

I did not test this but it should be fine. Let me know if anything comes up.

Comment: The problem with this is that you'll get `("(E,", "P)", "(F,", "K)")` as your contents.

Comment: a convoluted way would be to do a `.split(maxsplit=1)` to get the header, and then split the rest of the content with `.split(') (')` but I think a regex would be more suitable here

Comment: It does work but I think there is a problem when checking for membership. The output is KeyError: "Number1"

Comment: @IgnacioGarcia `print` your `dict` to get an idea of what it contains and how it is stored. You will figure it out.